# How to split up really long match on enum with many variants?

Tags: enums, rust, pattern-matching

What's the usual best practice to split up a really long match on an enum with dozens of variants to handle, each with dozens or hundreds of lines of code?

I've started to create helper functions for each case and just call those functions passing in the enum's fields (or whatever they're called). But it seems a bit redundant to have `MyEnum::MyCase{a,b,c} => handle_mycase(a,b,c)` many times.

And if that is the best practice, is it possible to destructure `MyEnum::MyCase` directly in that helper function's parameters, despite the fact that technically it's refutable, since realistically I already know I'm calling it with the right case?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the crate [enum_dispatch](https://docs.rs/crate/enum_dispatch/0.2.0) helps you.

IIRC, on a high level: It assumes that all your enum variants implement a trait with a function `handle_mycase`. Then `handle_mycase` can be called on the enum directly and will be dispatched to the concrete struct.